# Difference .buildUpon() and .build()?

Tags: android, uri

buildUpon() is used to get **builder** from Uri. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder#build())
and build() to get **URI** with attributes.

What is the reason/purpose to use buildUpon(), if we can just build URI ? 
or I am getting something wrong ?

Comment: `buildUpon()` creates a `Builder` on an existing `Uri`. After you've built upon that `Uri`, you call `build()` on the `Builder` to get the new `Uri` with the new stuff added. It's just a cleaner way to do it over doing a bunch of `String` manipulation.

Comment: @MikeM.so, if I create new URI I don`t have to use buildUpon(), right ?

Comment: `buildUpon()` is used if you want to change somehow your already existing `Uri`

Comment: Yeah, you can certainly write out the URI as a `String` yourself, and then `Uri.parse()` it, if you like. The `Builder` is handy if you already have a `Uri`, and you just need to modify it a bit. It's generally easier, and cleaner, than converting it to a `String`, then manipulating that, then converting back to a `Uri`.